# Can there be functions $g$ and $f$ such that $\rho_{f(X),g(X+Y)}^2 > \rho_{X,X+Y}^2$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, correlation

#### Motivation a special case

A special case of this question is an inequality between the Spearman's rank correlation and the Pearson correlation ([Why is the sum of individual Spearman's rho squared less than 1 as opposed to Pearson's r in a synthetic example?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/580496/why-is-the-sum-of-individual-spearmans-rho-squared-less-than-1-as-opposed-to-pe) ). The expectation of the squared sample Spearman's rank correlation will approach $\rho_{f(X),g(X+Y)}^2$ with $f$ and $g$ the cumulative distribution function of the variables $X$ and $X+Y$.

By trying out several different distributions for $X$ and $Y$ it seems that in all cases the Spearman's rank correlation coefficient is smaller than the Pearson's correlation coefficient.

Thinking about that question it seemed to me intuitive that the correlation between $X$ and $X+Y$ must be a maximum. When we apply a formula, then information gets lost and the correlation should decrease. I imagine that a correlation between $f(X)$ and $g(X+Y)$ can't be larger than a correlation between the original $X$ and $X+Y$.

#### General question

So I am wondering whether, beyond that example with the Spearman's rank correlation it is true in general for other functions as well:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then the correlation should decrease or at least stay the same when we apply functions to $X$ and $X+Y$.  $\rho_{f(X),g(X+Y)}^2 \leq \rho_{X,X+Y}^2$

Is this true?

Is there a simple proof for this?

---

Edit: Apparently there can be made many examples relatively easy. Could it also work when $Var(Y) > Var(X)$ and $f$ and $g$ are monotonic functions?

Comment: $f(X) = X+Y, G(X+Y)= X+Y?$

Comment: @Dave is $f(X) = X+Y$ a function of $X$?

Comment: Choosing $X \sim \mathrm{Expo}(1)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ as well as $f(X)=X^2$ and $g(X+Y)=(X+Y)^2$ should yield a counterexample.

Comment: Consider the empirical distribution of the points $(0,0), (1,1), \ldots, (n-1,n-1),(e^n,-e^n)$ for large integral $n.$  I hope these assertions are obvious: (1) the Spearman coefficient grows arbitrarily close to $1$ and $(2)$ the Pearson coefficient grows arbitrarily close to $-1$ as $n$ grows large.  This applies to your situation where $Y=0$ and $g$ is the identity on rational numbers and otherwise multiplies irrationals by $-1.$

Comment: @whuber that is an interesting example but it makes the Pearson correlation slightly smaller when I apply that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example:

A distribution $X$ with values $-1$ and $1$ and a distribution $Y$ with values $-0.5$ and $0.5$ (e.g. scaled Rademacher distributed variables).

Then let $g$ and $f$ be a sign function

$$g(x) = f(x) = \begin{cases}
 -1 & \quad \text{if $x<0$}\\
 0 & \quad \text{if $x=0$}\\
 1 & \quad \text{if $x>0$}\end{cases}$$

This makes $f(X) = g(X+Y)$ and makes the correlation $1$.

---

> Edit: Apparently there can be made many examples relatively easy. Could it also work when $Var(Y) > Var(X)$ and $f$ and $g$ are monotonic functions?

We can adapt the example from statmerkur and use $X \sim Exp(1)$ and $Y \sim N(0,4)$ and the functions $f(x) = g(x) = x^3$.